# Analysing the jQuery source

Tags: jquery

I have found two sets of videos that analyse the jQuery source code:

Julian Bucknall: [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeMFEz_ufZc) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeMFEz_ufZc)

Paul Irish: [here](http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/) and [here](http://paulirish.com/2011/11-more-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/)

Are there any other available ressources that guide through the jQuery source?

Comment: Have you taken some time on your own to read through the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) with the comments?